# CSS Modules not applying style - next.js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Using `next.js 13.1.1` with `/app`

I've been doing all of my styles through a `global.css` up until now, but I'm trying to migrate them into CSS Modules.

In my root `layout.js`, I have a Header component that imports from `./header.js`. This works fine with `global.css`.

I've made a module `../styles/header.module.css`, and I import it into `./header.js` with `import styles from "../styles/header.module.css";`, but then when I try to use it, for example with `<h1 className={styles.big_title}>`, none of the CSS is applied.

Any help would be much appreciated, I've been trying to fix this for hours.
No errors occur, the CSS just doesn't apply.

```js
// ./layout.js

import Header from "./header";
import Footer from "./footer";

import "../styles/global.css";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html>
      <head>
          <title>SB-Wiki</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <Header />
          <main>
              {children}
          </main>
          <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

```CSS
/* ../styles/header.module.css */

.big_title {
    color: red;
}
```

```js
// ./header.js

import styles from "../styles/header.module.css";

export default function Header() {
    return (
        <header>
            <p className={styles.big_title}>Test</p>
        </header>
    )
}
```

The styles display if I add `import styles from "../styles/header.module.css";` to the top of a `page.js` but that rather defeats the point of having a root `layout.js` as the framework is designed this way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `next.js` . You need to create config file for `next.config.js` in order to properly support your `CSS` .

```
module.exports = {
   cssModules: true,
     cssLoaderOptions: {
   importLoaders: 1,
  localIdentName: "[]",
 },
};
```

The config file will tell the `next.js` to treat your `CSS` files as `CSS`

Answer (score 1):

i'm using material-ui and I kind of faced the same problem, I had Header and Footer component inside of layout.js and none of my styles was applying till I used !important which is really annoying.
so what I did was injecting my css to material ui on the top of my component trees like this :

```
 import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'

    export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="fa-IR" dir='rtl' className={vazir.className}>
      <body>
        <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst> //this part is important
          <MainTheme>
            <MainContext>
              <DesktopHeader />
              <MobileHeader />
              <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: '#101820' }}>
                {children}
                <Footer />
              </Box>
            </MainContext>
          </MainTheme>
        </StyledEngineProvider>
      </body>
    </html >
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the problem persist for you actually, but [I created a similar application in Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/quizzical-breeze-gkn5wf?file=%2Fapp%2Fglobals.css%3A5%2C2) with your setup, and its worked perfectly as expected without any additional next.js configurations.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use it like this styles["big_title"]

```
// ./header.js

import styles from "../styles/header.module.css";

export default function Header() {
    return (
        <header>
            <p className={styles["big_title"]}>Test</p>
        </header>
    )
}
```