# CSS Modules not applying styles outside app folder - NextJS 13

Tags: javascript, css, next.js13, css-modules

I have a problem using css modules in NextJS 13. My styles just apllied at app folder. When i tried to run my script inside pages folder, my css modules not applied. What can i do?

I want my style applied at every script on my pages folder.

Comment: Is [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74965841/css-modules-not-applying-style-next-js-13) a good start?